# Induced nontrivial homomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am caught up in a minor detail on a qualifying exam problem I am doing:

Show that there are no injective continuous functions $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^2$ , $n>2$ with $f(0)=0$.

So far I have considered the punctured spaces at the origin, and so the problem changes to:

Show that there are no continuous injections from $\Bbb {R^n}-\{0\} \to \Bbb {R^2}-\{0\}$ for $n>2$.

To do this I want to look at the induced homomorphism between fundamental groups and say that it is nontrivial since the original function is injective. Can I say this? If so, why?

Comment: `\{0\}` ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

A continuous injective map doesn't necessarily induce an injective homomorphism on fundamental groups. Consider the embedding $S^1 \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^2$ for a counterexample.

What you need is the [Borsuk–Ulam theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk-Ulam_theorem). $f$ restricts to a continuous map $S^2 \to \Bbb R^2$, and this map cannot be injective by the theorem.

Comment: Nice proof but the fact that they said to assume $f(0)=0$ makes me think they had something else in mind.

Comment: @Seth That assumption is superfluous. You can always compose $f$ with a homeomorphism $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ that maps $f(0)$ to $0$.

Comment: They had something else in mind. Up until the last line was essentially given in a hint. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Yes, obviously it is a superfluous assumption.  I just meant that they probably added it to the statement because they thought that it would simplify the notation, which means they probably expected a proof using fundamental group somehow.